# Bounding pdf of discrete RV using a bound on its cdf

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ a random variable with values in $\mathbb{N}$

if there is a constant $C >0$ and a $\lambda \in ]0,1[$ verirfying
$$P(X>k)<C\lambda^k, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$$

how can we show that $P(X=k)=O(\lambda^k), \forall k\in \mathbb{N}$

this is my attempt to prove it

$$P(X>k)<C\lambda^k$$

$$\implies  1-P(X \leq k)<C\lambda^k$$

$$\implies P(X \leq k)>1-C\lambda^k$$

[screenshot of the page where i found this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4PEP.png)

Comment: Hint: $P(X=k) \leq P(X>k-1) < C \lambda^{k-1}$.

Comment: yes that's it, thank you